# How can i get substaction calculation row between multiple dates and display the percentage?

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

I have the following information using group by and some calculations

[image]

I'm trying to calculate the maximum difference value between several dates in this example are 3 dates (2022, 2021, 2020), the oldest date should calculate 0 because won't do substractions.

[image]

After detecting the maximun difference between the previous year, it must calculate the percentage:

[image]

After doing the query for maximum difference calculation between date rows. The final result should be this:

[image]

Demo with 4 dates: https://dbfiddle.uk/KF-d2KpR?hide=4

The following query is displaying without percentage:

```
 WITH cte1 AS (
 SELECT
 a.date_rehearsal,
 a.col1_val,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.date_rehearsal ORDER BY a.date_rehearsal DESC) AS rn
 FROM demo a
 ),
 cte2 AS (
 SELECT
 b.date_rehearsal,
 b.col1_val - COALESCE(LEAD(b.col1_val) OVER (PARTITION BY b.rn 
 ORDER BY b.date_rehearsal DESC), b.col1_val) AS diff
 FROM cte1 b)
 SELECT
 c.date_rehearsal AS 'Dates',
 MAX(c.diff) as 'max_col1_val_difference'
 FROM cte2 c
 GROUP BY c.date_rehearsal
 ORDER BY c.date_rehearsal DESC
```

[image]

Can you please help me this operation to display with percentage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FIrst - a dynamic number of columns will make it hard for MySQL to generate (and its easy for application language to transform to this display). Second relying on ordinal order of groups (and what is the order when there's no column specified),  so having a 1 2 3 values in a separate column would help. After you have that, look at using window functions.

Comment: A big part of the solution to this problem is called a [tag:pivot]. They're a notorious pain in the xxs neck in MySql.

Comment: What do you want to happen for leap years? (29th of Feb) Will it always be just 3 years in the data?

Comment: See `LAG()` and `LEAD()`.  They are "windowing" functions in MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to get the `ROW_NUMBER` by *date*, then `SELECT` the `MAX` difference, `GROUPED BY` *date*, using a subquery that will take the current *col1_val* and subtracting it from the subsequent row's value using `LEAD` partitioned by the `ROW_NUMBER` from the `CTE`. If the subsequent row is `NULL`, then subtract it from the current row's *col1_val* using `COALESCE`, which will return zero for the earliest year in your table (in your case, *2020*).

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
  a.date_rehearsal,
  a.col1_val,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.date_rehearsal ORDER BY a.date_rehearsal DESC) AS rn
  FROM demo a
)
SELECT
  c.date_rehearsal AS 'Dates',
  MAX(c.diff) as 'max_col1_val_difference',
  ROUND(MAX(c.diffPercent),2) as 'max_col1_val_percent',
  CONCAT(MAX(c.diff), ' (', ROUND(MAX(c.diffPercent),2), '%)') as 'max_dif_with_percentage'
  FROM (
     SELECT
     b.date_rehearsal,
     b.col1_val - COALESCE(LEAD(b.col1_val) OVER (PARTITION BY b.rn ORDER BY b.date_rehearsal DESC), b.col1_val) AS diff,
     (((b.col1_val - COALESCE(LEAD(b.col1_val) OVER (PARTITION BY b.rn ORDER BY b.date_rehearsal DESC), b.col1_val))/b.col1_val)*100) AS diffPercent
     FROM cte b) c
GROUP BY c.date_rehearsal
ORDER BY c.date_rehearsal DESC
```

**Result**:

| Dates | max_col1_val_difference | max_col1_val_percent | max_dif_with_percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-01 | 6 | 5.08 | 6 (5.08%) |
| 2021-07-01 | 10 | 10.00 | 10 (10.00%) |
| 2020-07-01 | 0 | 0.00 | 0 (0.00%) |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qYsaftzS).

Comment: Well now you just completely changed your question and sample data. My answer is based on your first fiddle data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tD-YMXSE).

Comment: Thanks for your support i tried your code but it only works when we try with 3 rows. Can you please check the edited post?

Comment: Hello @CarlosMorales, It doesn't work because I wrote my original answer around your original description/sample data in which you have changed. Please elaborate how you got your final result values of 118, 110, 0. Shouldn't it be 6, 10, 0? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it was my mistake because i didnt know how to ask about it. The final result yes should be 6, 10 and 0 but instead of those values i'm trying to detect the value row affected, if you check its on red label

Comment: oh nice...its showing  6, 10, 0, but is working with static dates, is there any way to work it with several dates?

Comment: I've made the query dynamic, please see my updated answer. I don't think there's anything else that can be done using my method at least.

Comment: Nice job!!! , i really appreciate your support and time. Can you please help me to add percentage? it is almost done. i spent 3 months trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's almost done? Lol, :) Sure, I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, i edited the post AND it's almost done. Also i started a started a Bounty for reward.

Comment: Updated with the %

Comment: Omg...take my Money sir

Comment: Glad I could help! That was a fun one!